# No declaration found for element xs:schema

Tags: xml

I would like to thank you first of all for your help... I have a problem with XSD and XML (no declaration found for element xs schema)...  this is my  code,
and tried to look for the problem and it took several days and nothing is why I ask for help.

xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmIns:dec="https://www.siged.sep.gob.mx/certificados" targetNamespace="https://www.siged.sep.gob.mx/certificados" elementFormDefault= "qualified">
<xs:element name="Dec">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="lpes">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Responsable">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:attribute name="curp" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="nombre" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="primerApellido" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="segundoApellido" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="idCargo" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="cargo" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="idNombrelnstitucion" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="nombrelnstitucion" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="idCampus" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="campus" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="idEntidadFederativa" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="entidadFederativa" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Rvoe">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:attribute name="numero" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="fechaExpedicion" type="xs:dateTime" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Carrera">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:attribute name="idCarrera" type="xs:integer" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="claveCarrera" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="nombreCarrera" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="idTipoPeriodo" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="tipoPeriodo" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="clavePlan" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Alumno">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:attribute name="numeroControl" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="curp" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="nombre" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="primerApellido" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="segundoApellido" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="idGenero" type="xs:integer" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="fechaNacimiento" type="xs:dateTime" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="foto" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="firmaAutografa" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Expedicion">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:attribute name="idTipoCertificacion" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="tipoCertificacion" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="fecha" type="xs:dateTime" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="idLugarExpedicion" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="lugarExpedicion" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Asignaturas" minOccurs="l" maxOccurs="l">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Asignatura" minOccurs="l" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:attribute name="idAsignatura" type="xs:integer" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="claveAsignatura" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="nombre" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="ciclo" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="calificacion" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="idObservaciones" type="xs:integer" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="observaciones" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="total" type="xs:int" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="asignadas" type="xs:int" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="promedio" type="xs:string" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Sep" minOccurs="0">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" namespace="any"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="version" use="required" fixed="l.0">
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute fixed="S" name="tipoCertificado" type="xs:integer" use="required">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="folioControl" type="xs:string" use="optional">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="sello" use="required" type="xs:string">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="certificadoResponsable" use="required" type="xs:string">
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="noCertificadoResponsable" use="required" type="xs:string">
</xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and the error is in this section:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmIns:dec="https://www.siged.sep.gob.mx/certificados" 
         targetNamespace="https://www.siged.sep.gob.mx/certificados" elementFormDefault= 
         "qualified">
```

thank you  so  much for  your help, I try to make a xml and give me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Document created with online XML Editor http://xmlgrid.net 2018/10/18 17:23:16  -->
   <Dec version="test attribute" tipoCertificado="test attribute" folioControl="test attribute" sello="test attribute" certificadoResponsable="test attribute" noCertificadoResponsable="test attribute">
         <lpes idNombrelnstitucion="test attribute" nombrelnstitucion="test attribute" idCampus="test attribute" campus="test attribute" idEntidadFederativa="test attribute" entidadFederativa="test attribute">
               <Responsable curp="test attribute" nombre="test attribute" primerApellido="test attribute" segundoApellido="test attribute" idCargo="test attribute" cargo="test attribute">test string</Responsable>
               <Responsable curp="test attribute" nombre="test attribute" primerApellido="test attribute" segundoApellido="test attribute" idCargo="test attribute" cargo="test attribute">test string</Responsable>
               <Responsable curp="test attribute" nombre="test attribute" primerApellido="test attribute" segundoApellido="test attribute" idCargo="test attribute" cargo="test attribute">test string</Responsable>
         </lpes>
         <lpes idNombrelnstitucion="test attribute" nombrelnstitucion="test attribute" idCampus="test attribute" campus="test attribute" idEntidadFederativa="test attribute" entidadFederativa="test attribute">
               <Responsable curp="test attribute" nombre="test attribute" primerApellido="test attribute" segundoApellido="test attribute" idCargo="test attribute" cargo="test attribute">test string</Responsable>
               <Responsable curp="test attribute" nombre="test attribute" primerApellido="test attribute" segundoApellido="test attribute" idCargo="test attribute" cargo="test attribute">test string</Responsable>
               <Responsable curp="test attribute" nombre="test attribute" primerApellido="test attribute" segundoApellido="test attribute" idCargo="test attribute" cargo="test attribute">test string</Responsable>
         </lpes>
         <lpes idNombrelnstitucion="test attribute" nombrelnstitucion="test attribute" idCampus="test attribute" campus="test attribute" idEntidadFederativa="test attribute" entidadFederativa="test attribute">
               <Responsable curp="test attribute" nombre="test attribute" primerApellido="test attribute" segundoApellido="test attribute" idCargo="test attribute" cargo="test attribute">test string</Responsable>
               <Responsable curp="test attribute" nombre="test attribute" primerApellido="test attribute" segundoApellido="test attribute" idCargo="test attribute" cargo="test attribute">test string</Responsable>
               <Responsable curp="test attribute" nombre="test attribute" primerApellido="test attribute" segundoApellido="test attribute" idCargo="test attribute" cargo="test attribute">test string</Responsable>
         </lpes>
         <Rvoe numero="test attribute" fechaExpedicion="test attribute">test string</Rvoe>
         <Rvoe numero="test attribute" fechaExpedicion="test attribute">test string</Rvoe>
         <Rvoe numero="test attribute" fechaExpedicion="test attribute">test string</Rvoe>
         <Carrera idCarrera="test attribute" claveCarrera="test attribute" nombreCarrera="test attribute" idTipoPeriodo="test attribute" tipoPeriodo="test attribute" clavePlan="test attribute">test string</Carrera>
         <Carrera idCarrera="test attribute" claveCarrera="test attribute" nombreCarrera="test attribute" idTipoPeriodo="test attribute" tipoPeriodo="test attribute" clavePlan="test attribute">test string</Carrera>
         <Carrera idCarrera="test attribute" claveCarrera="test attribute" nombreCarrera="test attribute" idTipoPeriodo="test attribute" tipoPeriodo="test attribute" clavePlan="test attribute">test string</Carrera>
         <Alumno numeroControl="test attribute" curp="test attribute" nombre="test attribute" primerApellido="test attribute" segundoApellido="test attribute" idGenero="test attribute" fechaNacimiento="test attribute" foto="test attribute" firmaAutografa="test attribute">test string</Alumno>
         <Alumno numeroControl="test attribute" curp="test attribute" nombre="test attribute" primerApellido="test attribute" segundoApellido="test attribute" idGenero="test attribute" fechaNacimiento="test attribute" foto="test attribute" firmaAutografa="test attribute">test string</Alumno>
         <Alumno numeroControl="test attribute" curp="test attribute" nombre="test attribute" primerApellido="test attribute" segundoApellido="test attribute" idGenero="test attribute" fechaNacimiento="test attribute" foto="test attribute" firmaAutografa="test attribute">test string</Alumno>
         <Expedicion idTipoCertificacion="test attribute" tipoCertificacion="test attribute" fecha="test attribute" idLugarExpedicion="test attribute" lugarExpedicion="test attribute">test string</Expedicion>
         <Expedicion idTipoCertificacion="test attribute" tipoCertificacion="test attribute" fecha="test attribute" idLugarExpedicion="test attribute" lugarExpedicion="test attribute">test string</Expedicion>
         <Expedicion idTipoCertificacion="test attribute" tipoCertificacion="test attribute" fecha="test attribute" idLugarExpedicion="test attribute" lugarExpedicion="test attribute">test string</Expedicion>
         <Asignaturas total="test attribute" asignadas="test attribute" promedio="test attribute">
               <Asignatura idAsignatura="test attribute" claveAsignatura="test attribute" nombre="test attribute" ciclo="test attribute" calificacion="test attribute" idObservaciones="test attribute" observaciones="test attribute">test string</Asignatura>
               <Asignatura idAsignatura="test attribute" claveAsignatura="test attribute" nombre="test attribute" ciclo="test attribute" calificacion="test attribute" idObservaciones="test attribute" observaciones="test attribute">test string</Asignatura>
               <Asignatura idAsignatura="test attribute" claveAsignatura="test attribute" nombre="test attribute" ciclo="test attribute" calificacion="test attribute" idObservaciones="test attribute" observaciones="test attribute">test string</Asignatura>
         </Asignaturas>
         <Sep>test string</Sep>
         <Sep>test string</Sep>
         <Sep>test string</Sep>
   </Dec>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the schema processor is saying that it can't find a declaration for the xs:schema element, this suggests that it is trying to validate the schema, when you actually want to be validating the instance document. Check how you invoked the schema processor, and that you didn't supply a reference to the schema document where it was expecting a reference to the instance document.

Comment: Hello, Michael Kay, thank you very much for taking your time to answer me, I thought I was dead in this problem. apologize my ignorance in the problem you would have the kindness to explain me in an easier way to be able to understand, thank you very much again for your help

Comment: I'm saying the problem might be in the way you are invoking the schema processor. Take a look at how you are requesting the validation, and if you can't see a problem there, post your code so that other people can look at it. So far we don't even know which schema processor you are using.